# Edit account information from android app

Tags: android, mysql

I am working on an android app with a group of people and we have our app connected to the database where we store user accounts for the app. We are making a my profile page and we want it to support features like edit password, email, ect. How would we go about doing that? So we need to give that user permission to their information on the database and allow them to edit their name, password, ect. We are new to android development, and I am now coming up with any sites on google on how to do this. Any links, tutorials, would be amazing.
Oh and our database is written in MySQL, its on a remote server.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't really seem like an Android question specifically. Seems to me there are two components here: the server-side component and the client side. The question about how to implement updating values in the database is a question about

1. how to expose such functionality in a web API
2. how to actually perform such CRUD operations in your MySQL database

In other words, think "thin client, thick server". Your app should be concerned only with the UI of updating a profile and with sending those updates values to the server that knows how to handle that. The latter part of this is purely a web development/API development question.

While this may not answer your question exactly, it does point you to the correct area of inquiry, which is oftentimes the most important skill in searching for an answer.